# onload for a jsp inside IFrame was setting the iframe to entire page/browser

Tags: javascript

I have an IFrame in a DIV with its SRC attribute being dynamically set by a JS function. So, if src="file.jsp", then an onload function(inside the body in file.jsp) that contains adjustments to some styles inside the file.jsp was hovering IFrame all over the webpage once it was done with the function triggered by onload. i.e., iframe is spreading all over the webpage. Please let me know what needs to be done to preserve the IFrame position after the onload function.

The Code in my onload function is as shown

```
function load() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('iip') > -1) {
        document.getElementById('peLibraryTreeDiv').style.width = "596px";
        parent.document.getElementById('privateEquityDiv').style.width =
                "96.9%";
        parent.document.getElementById('privateEquityDiv').style.top =
                "77px";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please rephrase because it is not clear what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I mean adding any type of content in onload() method of a file.jsp(this appears in an Iframe in a DIV) is leading to display the iframe itself entirely in the browser.

Comment: can you show the onload function and the html code of your div and the css of your div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a perfectly valid and working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script>
        function changeIframe(newLocation){
            document.getElementById("myIframe").src=newLocation;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="changeIframe('http://www.example.com')">
        <div style="width:650px;float:auto;border:1px dotted #cccccc;">
            <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.ebay.co.uk/" width="100%" height=750px marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=1 scrolling=auto>
              <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

please note that some websites cannot be added as src to an iframe like http://www.google.com (not sure why, I have made a question on SO here [can't add google.com as src to an IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141436/cant-add-google-com-as-src-to-an-iframe))