# can't add google.com as src to an IFrame

Tags: html, iframe, html4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

Why some websites can't be added as source to my iframe

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script>
        function changeIframe(newLocation){
            document.getElementById("myIframe").src=newLocation;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="changeIframe('http://www.example.com')">
        <div style="width:650px;float:auto;border:1px dotted #cccccc;">
            <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.ebay.co.uk/" width="100%" height=750px marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=1 scrolling=auto>
              <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If i change http://www.example.com to http://www.google.com it doesn't show any content. I have tested it with chrome, IE, FF.

Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: cannot delete because it has answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sets the x-frame-options response header to SAMEORIGIN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Answer (score 2):

Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page

See: [Mozilla Developer Network - The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)